# How can I test if a string can be converted to a decimal in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to extract some data from XML using Linq to XML, and I have the following code:

```
            commisionPct = XDocument.Parse(commissionXml)
                                    .Descendants("Range")
                                    .Attributes("commission")
                                    .Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Value))
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is I do not want it to exception if `x.Value` is not a decimal.  Normally I'd use `decimal.TryParse` but I am not sure of a clean way to do this inside of a linq statement.  I guess I could surround this with a try/catch block but I was curious if there was a better way to do this inside of Linq.

I would prefer it to return the decimal default value (0) if it's not a decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your `Select` like this:

```
//Linq
.Select(
    x =>
    {
         Decimal d;
         Decimal.TryParse(x.Value, out d);
         return d;
    })
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, create a method to handle it for you.

```
//Linq
.Select(x => DecimalTryParseOrZero(x.Value))
.FirstOrDefault();

Decimal DecimalTryParseOrZero(String input)
{
    Decimal d;
    Decimal.TryParse(x.Value, out d);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: It's pointless to set the variable to zero before calling `TryParse`. The value is always replaced by the value that the method puts there (which just happens to be zero if the value can't be parsed).

Comment: Good point, I wrote it differently and forgot to take that out when I trimmed the method back down.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TryParse` and make it return the result as a nullable decimal:

```
.Select(x => {
  decimal n;
  return Decimal.TryParse(x.Value, out n) ? n : (decimal?)null
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `decimal.TryParse`. Here's a simple example:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "cow", 
                                 "duck", "23", "42", "linq" };

decimal d = 0;
var nums = from x in strings
           select decimal.TryParse(x, out d) ? d : 0;
```

Using your example with the method syntax, it would look something like this:

```
decimal d = 0;
commisionPct = XDocument.Parse(commissionXml)
                        .Descendants("Range")
                        .Attributes("commission")
                        .Select(x => decimal.TryParse(x, out d) ? d : 0)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That doesn't select 0 when it can't be parsed.

Comment: I fixed this example so that it returns zero for non-decimal strings, as stipulated by the OP.